# Date Error in Pandas looking to resolve 1970 error

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following code in python to convert an object to date format:
df['MATURITY_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MATURITY_DATE'])

However, it keeps making the dates turn to 1970. The raw data looks like "20270601".

Any suggestions would be great, the data is coming in from a CSV and the CSV itself has 1M rows of data.

The Item is an object as you can see with df.info
MATURITY_DATE        198485 non-null  object

Thanks,

Comment: "The raw data looks like "20270601"" Okay, and what date should that number correspond to? Do you know? Where did the CSV file come from? Do you have any documentation that tells you how the data is formatted?

Comment: The date should correspond to 2027-06-01 (Year,month,day), no documentation from the data when I pull it up in excel it comes up as a date

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue: `pd.to_datetime("20270601")` -> `Timestamp('2027-06-01 00:00:00')`

Answer (score 0):

Does "20270601" is a unix time format?
if yes, use:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['MATURITY_DATE'],unit='s')
```

or

```
pd.to_datetime(df['MATURITY_DATE'],unit='ns')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Tried this the data does not update stays as datetime64[ns] and does not fix the issue.